# Implementing SeekBarChangeListener in RangeSeekBar

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using this library for range seek bar usage: https://github.com/Innovattic/range-seek-bar

When using the SeekBarChangeListener interface in activity level it compiles just fine:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RangeSeekBar.SeekBarChangeListener {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
}

override fun onStartedSeeking() {}
override fun onStoppedSeeking() {}
override fun onValueChanged(minThumbValue: Int, maxThumbValue: Int) {}
```

}

What is wish to do is implement SeekBarChangeListener on more internal level like so:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.rangeSeekBar.seekBarChangeListener(object : RangeSeekBar.SeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onStartedSeeking() {}
        override fun onStoppedSeeking() {}
        override fun onValueChanged(minThumbValue: Int, maxThumbValue: Int) {}

    })
}
```

}

But I get Unresolved reference on seekBarChangeListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct way

```
binding.rangeSeekBar.seekBarChangeListener = (object : RangeSeekBar.SeekBarChangeListener{
        override fun onStartedSeeking() {
        }

        override fun onStoppedSeeking() {
        }

        override fun onValueChanged(minThumbValue: Int, maxThumbValue: Int) {
        }
    })
```